# Problema insertando ñ en sqlserver y php

Tags: php, sql-server

Cuando quiero inserta una `ñ` en la bas de datos utilzando una query, sin pasar por PHP no tengo ningun problema, se inserta la `ñ` y la puedo visulizar correctamete. Utilizando la siguente query;

```
insert into dbo.ls_capacitadores (nombre) values('ñ')
SELECT * FROM ls_capacitadores order by id desc
```

`salida`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero ahora si yo quiero inserta la `ñ` utilizando el `odbc` de php para poder conectarme e insertar un registro, lo inserta. Estoy utilizando SQLServer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código tengo lo siguente:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate ");

$sql = "insert into dbo.ls_capacitadores (nombre) values('ñ')";
$db = new BaseDatos();
$db->query($sql);
```

Metodo `query()`

```php
public function query($query)
    {
        $this->connect();
        return odbc_exec($this->conn, $query);
    }
```

Método `connect()`

```php
public function connect()
    {
        $this->conn_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' . $this->host . ';DATABASE=' . $this->db . ';charset=utf8';
        $this->conn = odbc_connect($this->conn_string, $this->user, $this->pass);
    }
```

Comment: Asi?
`$this->conn_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' . $this->host . ';DATABASE=' . $this->db . ';charset=utf8;Client_CSet=UTF-8';`
No funciona, hace lo mismo

Comment: En que `encoding` estas guardando tus archivos? Cual es [`default_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) configurado en PHP? Intentaste usar `CharacterSet` y no `charset` en el string de conexión? Por ejemplo `;CharacterSet=UTF-8`

Comment: `default_charset="UTF-8"`
Ya probe cambiar `charset` por `CharacterSet`
En este servidor corren varios proyectos, y solo tengo problema con este proyecto.

Comment: Intenta agregar `N` antes del texto a insertar, por ejemplo, `$sql = "insert into dbo.ls_capacitadores (nombre) values(N'ñ')";`. [Más info](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: hace exactamente lo mismo, de todas formas es un problema general no solo con la ñ sino con cualquier caractes que tenga tilde